# How to render a popover React component for a FullCalendar event?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap, popover, fullcalendar-5

This may be a simpler problem than I am making it out to be, but I am still fairly new to React and this is my first time using FullCalendar. It has gone okay so far... up to trying to implement tooltips/popovers for events. There are a lot of great examples that use FullCalendar V.4 with 'eventRender' and for V.5 I have only managed to see examples involving the basic 'alert()' function with 'eventClick'.
What I am attempting to do is render the React-Bootstrap Popover Overlay when an event in FullCalendar is clicked. I know I am stuck on not understanding how to render the Popover with FullCalendar's new event render hook: 'eventDidMount'.

Here is what I have at the moment for reference, but as you could guess it is not working:

```
export function Calendar({ calData }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [target, setTarget] = useState(null);
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const handleEventClick = (event) => {
        setShow(!show);
        setTarget(event.target);
    };
    const EventPopover = (info) => {
        return(
            <div ref={ref}>
                <Overlay
                    show={show}
                    target={target}
                    container={ref}
                >
                    <Popover>
                        ...
                    </Popover>
                </Overlay>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <FullCalendar
            plugins={dayGridPlugin}
            events={calData}
            eventClick={handleEventClick}
            eventDidMount={EventPopover}
        />
    )
```

This is just the calendar component that is placed into a container for the App. Everything is actually rendered inside the React 18 'createRoot()'/'root.render()' method of my 'index.js' file.

I know I am not understanding the 'eventDidMount' hook correctly. But what is really stumping me is not being able to identify the Bootstrap element for the Overlay component to target - like the  element in the documentation examples.

In my head, the 'eventClick' is mimicking the 'onClick' event that is used for my state hooks and event handlers, but is the 'eventDidMount' mimicking the previous 'eventRender' hook? And if so, then how do you define the targeted element to attach the popover Overlay? I've been staring at this for far too long and realized I just need to ask for some help. So, thank you in advance to anyone who can help me understand this!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out a solution. I never did figure out how to implement the bootstrap popover even though I'm fairly certain I was close - but using tippy.js implemented well within the rest of the bootstrap styling on my page.
For those trying to use a popover in a React v18 framework with FullClanedar v5 - I have become a believer in Tippy and it's ease of use. Here is what it looks like for my Calendar component.

```
export function Calendar ({ calData }) {
   return (
      <div className='calendar-container'>
         <FullCalendar
            plugins={dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin}
            events={calData}
            eventClick={ (info) => {
               console.log(info.event.title)
            }}
            eventDidMount={ (info) => {
               tippy(info.el, {
                  trigger: 'click',
                  touch: 'hold',
                  allowHTML: true,
                  content:
                     `<h3>${info.event.extendedProps.author}</h3>
                      <hr/>
                      <h5>${info.event.extendedProps.roomNumber}</h5>
                      <hr/>
                      <p>${info.event.extendedProps.description}</p>`,
               });
            }}
         />
      </div>
   )
};
```

You can kind of see how I'm gonna try to re-create what the bootstrap popover looked like - hence as to why I am a believer in Tippy because if I can recreate it with something I know works then I don't have to make bootstrap work, right? Anywho - I don't have great answers to some of my questions because it works in my head but not in a way I can explain to others yet.

If someone figures out how targeting the event  elements for the react-bootstrap popover works, then I'd love to learn where I fell short at. But in the meantime look at tippy! (P.S. it wasn't obvious to me at first, but it is the up-to-date model of tooltip.js that the codepen.io example from FullCalendar's documentation references).

Comment: Also, it didn't even need state hooks management! I knew it was much simpler than I was making it out to be.